# Joining two tables with pattern matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to joining two tables in PostgreSQL.

Table 1: `O_REMEDY_PEOPLEGROUP`

| manager_name | manager_hierarchy |
| --- | --- |
| farhanpat | raju jacob watson |
| soumyvant | neha william |
| amitk | piyush shawn |
| brian | david warner |

Table 2: `Org_details`

| org_name | vp_details |
| --- | --- |
| org1 | jacob |
| org2 | piyush |
| org3 | neha |

We want to search for each VP if it's present in the manager hierarchy of table 1.
If present, third column should report `org_name`, else null.

Output Table:

| manager_name | manager_hierarchy | org_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| farhanpat | raju jacob watson | org1 |
| soumyvant | neha william | org3 |
| amitk | piyush shawn | org2 |
| brian | david warner | null |

Comment: Every time you store a set of values as a comma-separated string in a relational database, Tinkerbell dies.

Comment: You should normalise your table design. Having your manager hierarchy as an array is not a good design and makes querying your data unnecessarily complicated - as you are finding out

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are different databases with different syntax and functionality. Please delete the tag of the database you're not using.

Comment: I've fixed the table for string of the first table for you, please edit and fix the other two tables in the same way.

Comment: I have edited my tables and developed new tables to remove the issue of set of values as comma-seperated strings.

Please suggest how do I now bring up the join with better performance.

updated the question.

Comment: @frpfarhan Using a space-separated string has just exactly the same problem as a comma-separated string. It might even be worse since surnames easily can contain spaces.

Comment: @NickW Using a real *array* (i.e. type `text[]`) is still much better than a comma-separated string (or space-separated string). And it's actually quite easy to query in Postgres. The problem with it is that you cannot put foreign key constraints on the elements.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately we do not have a provision to change the table design, its read from the source table. It is in space separated string. Any suggestions how can we perform the join.

Comment: @frpfarhan What do you mean by "*it is read from the source table*"?

Comment: @Bergi client table I mean which we do not have provisions to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While stuck on your unfortunate design with multiple values concatenated as single string, this should work as efficiently as it gets (while being accurate):

```sql
SELECT r.manager_name, r.manager_hierarchy
    , (SELECT d.org_name
       FROM   string_to_table(r.manager_hierarchy, ' ') vp_details
       JOIN   org_details d USING (vp_details)
       LIMIT  1) AS org_name
FROM   o_remedy_peoplegroup r;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_fVTRuL9)

[`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.35.1.1.1) was added with Postgres 14. Replace with `unnest(string_to_array())` in older versions.

Since it's undefined in the question I pick the first arbitrary match with `LIMIT 1`. (There might be multiple.)

If `org_details` isn't trivially small, there should be an index on `(vp_details)` to get index scans, or even on `(vp_details, org_name)` to get index-only scans.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed data stored as comma separated list  will bring more and more troubles.

See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

As per the question.

In your particular case you have stored not only a comma separated string but `[` ,`]` symbols and a space between 'words'.

So FIND_IN_SET cant be used without doing some replace.

The following query replace the above symbols and the space with empty.

Try

```
select orp.manager_name,
       orp.manager_hierarchy,
       od.org_name
from O_REMEDY_PEOPLEGROUP orp
left join Org_details od on  FIND_IN_SET(od.VPdetails, replace(replace(replace(orp.manager_hierarchy,']','') ,'[',''),' ',''));
```

Another options is using LIKE

```
select orp.manager_name,
       orp.manager_hierarchy,
       od.org_name
from O_REMEDY_PEOPLEGROUP orp
left join Org_details od on replace(replace(replace(orp.manager_hierarchy,']','') ,'[',''),' ','')
LIKE CONCAT('%', od.VPdetails , '%')
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/_u-ed2m_)

**Note**. No index will be used in either query, so performance for large data set will be terrible

Comment: I have edited my tables and developed new tables to remove the issue of set of values as comma-seperated strings.

Please suggest how do I now bring up the join with better performance.

updated the question.

Comment: @frpfarhan you have just remove the comma and the `[]` symbols. You need to normalize the data. For example for the row `farhanpat raju jacob watson` with the normalize data you need to have three rows `farhanpat raju`, `farhanpat jacob` and  `farhanpat watson`